# Having trouble in PresentDismiss & NavigateViewController push/pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have the whole app embedded in UINavigationController. Now there is the Home Screen that has several modules for user to choose. Now, when the user clicks on the module it is NAVIGATED and if user desires to choose some another module from any other modules available, there is a button in navigation bar, which PRESENTS the HomeViewController modally on top of the current module and then user can choose any module from there which will NOT BE PRESENTED instead they will NAVIGATE.

Now what I have done is made a delegate called navigate on HomeViewController and will be override by viewcontrollers of each module and it will take the reference of the new ViewController with it. Then when this method is called I have first dismissViewController the HomeViewController and then navigated to the new ViewController that I have the reference.

Now, what the real issue is that SOMETIMES there is a jerk when navigating from one module to other and sometime it works fine. That why I am not able to debug also. The jerk is that when a module is clicked from HomeViewController, the home screen disappears and the appears again and then it actually navigates.

The code for navigating to a module from HomeViewController is

```
RadiusSearchViewController *rad = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RadiusSearchViewController"];
[self.delegate navigate:rad];
```

This navigation overrided method in all modules is

```
-(void)navigate:(UIViewController*)uiViewController{
NSLog(@"inside navigate method");
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I assure you that it is coming in this method.

Now the code that presents the HomeViewController modally is

```
ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0];
vc.delegate = self;
vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
vc.definesPresentationContext = YES;
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
vc.fromOutside = true;
NSLog(@"Presneting...");
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The reason for PRESENTING and NOT NAVIGATING the HomeViewController is that it comes on the top of the current module in transparent form which is necessary.

REMEMBER: It happens sometimes not all of the time. Like you can say half of the times.

Comment: [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];  this should be like  [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];}]; this will make sure navigation view controller will be called after dismiss is done. check and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @KarunPant75 working fine.. Lets see how good it continues to work.. Thanks

Comment: added this as an answer for anyone else who has same problem, accept if it works or atleast upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
```

this should be changed to...

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
    completion:^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:uiViewController animated:YES];
    }];
```

this will make sure navigation view controller will be called after dismiss is done. check and see if it solves your problem.